# Azure Websocket doesnt work for my application suddenly

Tags: azure, websocket, .net-core

Maybe someone knows what jus happened? I have my application .net core running on Azure. Suddenly my application can't create any WebSocket handshake. I have allowed azure to have WebSocket, on my local machine it works well and creates a connection.

Have no idea what just have happened.

By the way, it started to throw 307 response codes on azure, when WebSocket client tries to connect.

Comment: This week we had a similar issue in production on an Azure environment. Out of nowhere 307 redirects. We suspect a bug has been introduced recently that is causing this. Our fix was removing all calls to UseHttpsRedirection and let Azure handle the redirection with "app service > tls/ssl settings and enable HTTPS only".

Comment: Yes, I have figured this out as well(forgot to answer). I have some WebSocket clients who don't have SSL (not WSS) on development env. Just imagine what would happen if it all was in production env, because then all WS connections are disabled and no handshake made in azure. Never thought that kind of mistakes can occur from Azure.

Comment: @Dennis1679   and Andrius, could you post your answer to help others to find the answer easily?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem on Azure everyone who uses UseHttpsRedirection middleware should temporarily remove it. If you still want to keep redirections of HTTPS request. You should let Azure handle redirections by going to AppServices -> TLS/SSL settings -> HTTPS only make it ON.

But it is still a temporary fix until we get some news from Azure about it.